# Is it ok to have two events $A$ and $B$ so that for one person $A$ occurs before $B$ but for another $B$ preceds $A$

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, causality, observers, time-dilation

Imagine two laser beams A and B are released at the same moment to bounce between two mirrors, A was moving and B was at rest, doing the calculations I found that for a person at rest B would reach the upper mirror before A because in his frame of reference A travels less distance.  but for another person in the same reference frame of A, A would reach the upper mirror first.
Is that OK in relativity![image: the upper is moving and the lower is constant]

Comment: Can you add a diagram please?  "Upper Mirror"?

Comment: I've added an image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's ok!  You've stumbled upon one of the basic strange phenomena of relativity.

Comment: one last question : so in two reference frames with relative velocity, for every one of them the clocks in the other frame of reference runs slower ?? @garyp

Answer (score 1):

If the two laser beams are emitted at the same moment in one frame, they will not be emitted at the same moment in another frame moving relative to the original frame. This is relativity of simultaneity. Since the light beams start at different times, it's not a problem for them to travel a different distances.